# Trim the output digits

Tags: java, hex

Here is my code.

```
package solution;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Stack;
public class Acadox {
    public static boolean isOperator(String c)
    {
        return ( "+".equals(c) || "-".equals(c) || "&".equals(c) || "|".equals(c) || "~".equals(c) || "X".equals(c));
    }

    /* public String convert(String str)
    {
          char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
          StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
          for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
          {
            strBuffer.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
          }
          return strBuffer.toString();
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try
        {
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String s[]=read.readLine().split(" ");

            Stack<String> st=new Stack<String>();

            st.push(s[0]);
            int i=1;

            int num1,num2,decRes;
            String hexres,result;


            if(isOperator(s[1]) && !"~".equals(s[1]))
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            else if(!isOperator(s[s.length-1]))
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    if(!isOperator(s[i]))
                    {
                        st.push(s[i]);
                        i++;
                    }  
                    else
                    {
                        if("+".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);

                            decRes=num1+num2;                          

                            if(decRes>65535)
                                hexres="FFFF";
                            else
                                hexres=Integer.toHexString(decRes);

                            st.push(""+hexres);
                        }
                        else if("-".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);

                            decRes=num1-num2; 

                            if(decRes<0)
                                hexres="0000";
                            else
                                hexres=Integer.toHexString(decRes);

                            hexres=Integer.toHexString(decRes);

                            st.push(""+hexres);
                        }
                        else if("&".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                             num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);
                             num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);

                            decRes=num1&num2;                          

                            hexres=Integer.toHexString(decRes);

                            st.push(""+hexres);
                        }
                        else if("|".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                             num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);

                            decRes=num1|num2;                          

                            hexres=Integer.toHexString(decRes);

                            st.push(""+hexres);
                        }
                        else if("~".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);

                            decRes=~num1;                          

                            hexres=Integer.toHexString(decRes);

                            st.push(""+hexres);
                        }
                        else if("X".equals(s[i]))
                        {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop(),16);

                            decRes=num1^num2;                          

                            hexres=Integer.toHexString(decRes);

                            st.push(""+hexres);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                }
                while(st.size()!=1);
                result=st.pop().toUpperCase(); 
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I calculate functions like `(5 7 + )` I am getting the correct answer. But I want to have this answer in the following format.

```
5 7 +  = 000C
```

So how can I change the answer to the following format?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, i misread your question. Could you please mention what do you get?

Comment: I get the decimal value.But I need the hex value with format.

Comment: The code looks good to me, you use `toHexString` everywhere. Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.toHexString(12)` method of `Integer` class and then can use padding to append zeros in front

For `'000c'` do like this,

```
String.format("%4s",Integer.toHexString(12)).replace(" ", "0")
```

**OR USE Apache commons StringUtils**

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.leftPad(Integer.toHexString(12), 4, "0"));
```

### OUTPUT

```
000c
```

Comment: I need the answer like this . 000C